# Enabling/transferring .ppk that already created on Windows on Transmit on iMac?

Tags: ssh

I have a Windows Vista with a secure connection to my Centos server, using SSH pair keys. I would like to use the same .PPK on iMac. I have used PuttyGen to create .PEM extension but it is not working.

I also created a new pair keys on iMac and appended the .PUB to the know_host file on Centos server. But this one is not working either.

Can anyone please walk me through trouble shooting? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SSH doesn't use .PEM or .PPK files. For SSH keypairs you should have two files, a private key (`id_rsa`) and a public key (`id_rsa.pub`).

The `id_rsa` file is the one on your Mac (or Windows Vista PC) and the `id_rsa.pub` file's contents should be copied to the file `authorized_keys`, **NOT** `known_hosts` on your CentOS server.

The location of the `authorized_keys` file on the CentOS server will be in:

`~/.ssh`

Another option would be to generate a new SSH keypair on the Mac. You can find instructions on how to do this here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-connect-to-your-droplet-with-ssh

Comment: Thanks Toby! Here is what I did:    1) ssh-keygen -t rsa  2) cat a_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys, then restart sshd.. but not working .. i am getting this error .Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic)

Comment: I don't know what would cause that error message. I would see if you can locate the private key on your PC and copy it to the mac.